# CasperJS is not clicking my XPath item

Tags: javascript, xpath, casperjs

```
casper.then(function() {
    console.log("Click Change Password");
    casper.click(x('//*[@id="mainMenu"]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a'));
});
```

I know it's the correct XPath. I downloaded Chrome's XPath plugin and verified that it is the correct Xpath

My console says

> CasperError: Cannot dispatch mousedown event on nonexistent selector:
>   xpath sele ctor: //*[@id="mainMenu"]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a
>   C:/CasperJS/modules/casper.js:1355 in mouseEvent
>   C:/CasperJS/modules/casper.js:462 in click   G:/Projects/index.js:137 
>   C:/CasperJS/modules/casper.js:1553 in runStep
>   C:/CasperJS/modules/casper.js:399 in checkStep

Any help would be greatly appreciated

HTML From First Page

```
<input alt="Select" class="image  selectIcon"   name="SUBMIT-chn:$INTERNAL_password.pss"  src="docs/pics/select.png"  title="Select"   type="image"  />
```

HTML From Second Page (i need to enter data into the password field then click the submit button)

```
<input class="password text "  maxlength="250" name="_MYPW"    type="password"  />
<input  class="submit "   name="SUBMIT-VERIFY.x"       type="submit" value="Verify password" />
```

HTML From 3rd Page (I need to click the A HREF). [My CasperJS code above was suppose to execute Page 3. but it looks like I never navigated to this page]

```
<a   href="pss.exe?TRANSACTION=CGI_JUMP&SESSDATA=random&SKIN=default&LANG=en-US"        >
  Change passwords
</a>
```

Comment: Try to make screenshot before click - maybe page did not loaded yet etc.
http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#capture

Comment: Thanks. I just did that and if the screenshot is accurate it looks like that none of the previous commands (click link, enter form data, etc) worked. I am at the initial login page

Comment: Can you share html somehow? Maybe simplified..

Comment: Sure I'll update the HTML

Comment: @MichaelPlakhov I've updated the HTML (simplified and parts pertinent to the issue).

Comment: @ArtjomB.thanks for the info

Comment: The element you're trying to click is the `<a>` on page 3? but you don't actually navigate to page 3... so it sounds like the problem is not in the xpath, but in whatever caused you not to navigate to page 3. Unless I misunderstood something?